# How to transfer input data from a private void GUI to an ArrayList in a java class?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I need help with a specific problem in my class project. The goal of the project is to create a program in which you can register how much shares you own. Information that's required is the company name, how many shares you own and their respective value. I created a GUI class and a class where the information is transferred to. The input comes from a private void. I'm having trouble finding a way to transfer the input from the private void to a an arraylist in a class outside it.

Here is how I initialized the arraylist in the GUI class.

```
public class GUISharePortfolio_1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<SharePackage.Share> Package = new ArrayList<SharePackage.Share>();
```

Next is how I get the company name, number of shares and their value from the GUI. Since it is a private void I have to transfer that information to the SharePackage class.

```
private void CreatePortfolioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String name;
    double number;
    double value;

    name = CompanyNameField.getText();
    number = Double.parseDouble(NumberOfSharesField.getText());
    value = Double.parseDouble(ValueOfShareField.getText());

    Package.CompanyName(name);
    Package.NumberOfShares(number);
    Package.ValueOfShare(value);

}
```

I'm getting an error saying "cannot find symbol" under the CompanyName, NumberOfShares and ValueOfShare.

The public class to which the info should be transferred is this:

```
    package shareportfolio;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SharePackage
{
    private ArrayList<Share> Package = new ArrayList<Share>();

public class Share
{
    private String companyname;
    private double numberofshares;
    private double valueofshare;

    Share(String companyname, double numberofshares, double valueofshare)
    {
        this.companyname = companyname;
        this.numberofshares = numberofshares;
        this.valueofshare = valueofshare;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String name)
    {
        companyname = name;
    }

    public String getCompanyName()
    {
        return(companyname);
    }

    public void setNumberOfShares(double number)
    {
        numberofshares = number;
    }

    public double getNumberOfShares()
    {
        return(numberofshares);
    }

    public void setValueOfShare(double value)
    {
        valueofshare = value;
    }

    public double getValueOfShare()
    {
        return(valueofshare);
    }

}
```

}

I would appreciate any help very much.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error (i.e. stack trace) you are receiving?

Answer (score 2):

You have a field named Package, who's type is ArrayList.  ArrayList doesn't have a method called CompanyName.  What you're probably trying to do is something like:

```
Package.add(new SharePackage.Share(companyname, numberofshares, valueofshares));
```

You have two such fields named 'Package', so not sure which one you're trying to add to.  Maybe you're under the impression the fields are somehow the same one.  They are not.

BTW: Definitely learn Java coding style before submitting this to anyone.  You are naming fields with UpperCamelCase which makes it very difficult for a java programmer to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

user1207705 that was the answer. I modified it to:

```
String name;
    double number;
    double value;

    name = CompanyNameField.getText();
    number = Double.parseDouble(NumberOfSharesField.getText());
    value = Double.parseDouble(ValueOfShareField.getText());

    Package.add(new SharePackage.Share(name, number, value));
```

Thank you for your help and I will work on Java coding style.